# Are identification requests of foreign language text in movies on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I was recently watching the Disney movie Aladdin, when I froze the frame and saw some Arabic text in the movie.

[image]

Are requests for identification of such foreign text (often inserted as in-jokes) on topic?

As a secondary question, if these questions are not considered on topic, where will they be on topic?

Comment: I would argue that this is trivia, as it clearly has no significance to the plot.

Comment: By the way, the word you are looking for instead of "identification" (which has an entirely different meaning on this site) is "translation".

Answer (score 4):

We actually already have several of these types of questions (for example [Translating the Jive...](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/11208/5603)).

Personally I don't see an issue with them, I find the counter of "this is trivia" to be invalid as you don't know it's not relevant to the plot until after it has been translated (no, I'm not denying the potential for this to end up in some trivia-ish questions).

If after a question of this type has been answered it's obvious that it's trivia, you can always downvote as "not useful".

Comment: If it were relevant to the plot, it would be translated on screen...

Comment: That's not always the case...